# Why does my website start behind the address bar in mobile safari?

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, safari

My website goes all the way up in mobile safari, in such a way that the top part of the logo is obscured by the permanently visible address bar. What should be changed in the code for the website to start below the adres bar (as is normal)?

The website I'm having trouble with is: https://www.chroma.nl/chromamichiel

Edit: Part of the html is based on this demo from google: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/ui-element-samples/parallax/, which seems to be working fine in mobile safari... However I cannot spot any differences that cause this inconsistency.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
.viewport {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.width {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}
.item {
height: 2000px;
width: 100%;
background-color: blue;
background-image: url(www.lorempixel.com/1000/1000/sport/);
background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body> 
  <div class="viewport" > 
    <div class="width">
      <div class="item">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question itself. See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

Answer (score 0):

Your html looks like this

```
<body> 
  <div class="viewport" > 
    <div style="max-width: 1200px; margin:auto;">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Try this css to see if it gives a more cross browser result.

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
html {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-display: swap;
  color: #555;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.viewport {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.viewport > div {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, without height and width specified in the viewport, it breaks the website. When added back height:100% and width:100% the issue remains...